# Фильтрация Laravel 7.0

Tags: laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать фильтрацию товара, как на фото максимально не трудозатратным способом. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее большое спасибо

Comment: Точно так же реализовать, как и не в laravel. Добавляете нужные поля в форму (или собираете значения вручную, как вам удобно..) и при сабмите проверяете - если пришли не пустые данные - добавляете их в запрос

Comment: У вас примера случайно нет? На словах сложно разобраться

Comment: Использовать пакет https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v2/introduction. 1) Разобраться как он работает 2) добавить свои типы фильтров - понадобится для цены